# Making nested/recursive directories using Perl

Tags: perl

I have written a C++ program that reads in a file and outputs the file with the same name with slight modifications. Now I need to browse recursively into the directory (of any package) and then create files in a separate directory having same directory structure.

I can browse into the directory by using

```
@file_list = `find <package directory> -name '*.cpp'`;
```

And I'm trying to execute my program like this:

```
foreach (@file_list) {
    # This gives error as sh: other_dir/./lev1/lev2/filename.cpp: not found
    ./myexe $_ other_dir/$_;
}
```

Previously I had written a shell script which worked good with packages having files in a single directory. The script is as follows:

```
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2 #echo off
  3 rm -rf demac_dir
  4 mkdir demac_dir
  5 for i in `ls *.h *.cpp`
  6 do
  7 echo processing file ${i} ...
  8 ./main ${i} demac_dir/${i}
  9 done
```

Now I'm trying to so the same thing with a package (i.e. [wxWidgets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WxWidgets)) which has .cpp and .h files in nested subdirectories. So I wrote the following Perl script (after ysth's suggestion).

```
  1 #!/usr/bin/perl -l
  2 use File::Path 'make_path';
  3 use File::Basename 'dirname';
  4
  5 `rm -rf demac_dir`;
  6 `mkdir demac_dir`;
  7 @l1 =  `find . -name '*.h'`;
  8 @l2 =  `find . -name '*.cpp'`;
  9 @l3 =  `find . -name '*.cc'`;
 10 push(@l , @l1, @l2, @l3);
 11 foreach (@l) {
 12   print "processing file $_ ...";
 13   make_path( dirname( "demac_dir/$_" ));
 14   ## `touch touch demac_dir/$_`;
 15   `sudo ./main $_ demac_dir/$_`;
 16 }
 17
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Err, you are missing a system() or something there that I presume is in your real code.

To make the directories you need, try:

```
use File::Path 'make_path';
use File::Basename 'dirname';

foreach (@file_list) {
    make_path( dirname( "other_dir/$_" ) );
    ...
}
```

Update: seeing your code, it looks like you are leaving newlines on the end of the filenames, which are probably causing you trouble (though I don't see why your ./main processor would produce the error you say it does...).

Add a `chomp(@l);` before your foreach loop.

Comment: yeah i'm getting the nested directories now. but still when i execute the command
     `./myexe $_ other_dir/$_`; 
i get the same error 
        sh: other_dir/./lev1/lev2/filename.cpp: not found

Comment: Why would you expect the file to be there? Your find command is looking for files in `<package directory>`, whatever that is. Your command is prefixing the paths found by find with 'other_dir/'.

Comment: You're going to have to show your actual code to get more help.

Comment: @David Hammen, I need the files from the <package directory> and after 'processing', i need to put the files in same order in   other_dir directory

Answer (score 1):

Check the FileHandler.pm and TemplateGenerator.pm from [morphus](http://code.google.com/p/morphus/downloads/list)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but i got the things working with ysth's suggestions. will look at morpus when i have some extra time.